# The paraboloid $z = x^2 + y^2$ has no conjugate points at $p = (0,0,0)$

Tags: proof-verification, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, surfaces

Can someone check if I am correct? This is exercise 2 in Do Carmo (Surface and curves) in chapter 5.5.

Let $S = \{ z = x^2 + y^2 \}$ with geodesic $\gamma(0) = p = (0,0,0)$ then clearly $T_pS = \{ (x,y,0) \}$.

Now since the paraboloid has positive Gaussian curvature, we cannot invoke the theorem involving empty conjugate locus. So I thought we have to go to Proposition5 to show that the exponential map $\exp_p:T_pS \to S$ is regular. That is it has no critical points (and hence no conjugate points relative to $p$). But I can't think of how to do it without knowing what the map should be.

So for the surface $\sigma (x,y) = (x,y,x^2 + y^2)$, the velocity of the curve on the surface is $\gamma' = (x',y',0)$. Now it is also equivalent to show that the Jacobi field along this geodesic is in fact $0$.

By Corollory 4 (of proposition 4), Jacobi fields along $\gamma$ with $J(0) = J(\ell) = 0$ must be orthogonal to the velocity, that is $(J(s),\gamma'(s)) = 0$.

Hence by inspection, one could take $J(s) = (-y',x',-)$. Here is where I am not sure if I can do this. Since $\gamma$ is a geodesic, $\gamma'' = (x'',y'',z'') = (0,0,0)$. Thus $J'(s) = (-y'',x'',-) = (0,0,0)$. Now I want to say something like since $J = 0$ on the end points and it has vanishing derivative that $J = 0$. But there is a lot of shaky arguments I have written.

EDIT: It just occured to me that in fact the last component of $J(s)$ is $0$. But whether $J(s)=(-y',x',0)$ is debatable since we can insert a smooth function $h(s)$ such that $J(s) = -h(s)(-y',x',0)$.

Comment: The one-liner is to recall what Jacobi fields are measuring.

Comment: @user10354138 it is the rate at which "nearby" geodesics (in the variational) deviate from the original geodesic.

Answer (score 3):

Let $S$ be the paraboloid $S = \{(x,y,z) : z = x^2 + y^2\}$, and let $\gamma : [0, a] \to S$ be a geodesic starting at $p = (0,0,0)$. Let $J$ be a Jacobi field along $\gamma$ with $J(0) = 0$. By the definition of a Jacobi field given in do Carmo's Curves and Surfaces on page 363, we can find a smooth variation $f : (-\varepsilon, \varepsilon) \times [0, a] \to S$ of $\gamma$ such that

1. $J$ is the variational field of $f$, i.e. $J(t) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial s}(0, t)$, and
2. for each $s \in (-\varepsilon, \varepsilon)$, the variational curve $f_s(t) = f(s, t)$ is a geodesic starting from $p$.

Any geodesic of the paraboloid $S$ starting at $p = (0,0,0)$ must be a meridian, which is proven in Example 5 on page 258 of do Carmo. Therefore
$$
f_s(t) = (t \cos \theta(s), t \sin \theta(s), t^2)
$$
(up to reparametrization in $t$) for some angle function $\theta(s)$. We show that $\theta : (-\varepsilon, \varepsilon) \to \mathbb{R}$, defined by the above equation, is differentiable at $0$. If $\phi(u,v) = (v \cos u, v \sin u, v^2)$ is the parametrization of $S$ described in the aforementioned example, then for sufficiently small $s$, we can write the function $\theta$ as
$$
\theta(s) = (\pi_2 \circ \phi^{-1})(f(s, a)).
$$
As a composition of differentiable functions (for sufficiently small $s$, so that $f(s,a)$ is in a neighbourhood of $\gamma(a)$ in which $\phi$ is a diffeomorphism), this must be differentiable at $s = 0$. (In fact, it is differentiable for all sufficiently small $s$.)

Now, since $J$ is the variational field, we see that if $J(a) = 0$, then
$$
(0,0,0) = J(a) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial s}(0, a) = (-a \theta'(0) \sin \theta(0), a \theta'(0) \cos \theta(0), 0).
$$
Since $a \neq 0$, and since $\sin \theta(0)$ and $\cos \theta(0)$ are not simultaneously zero, we have that $\theta'(0) = 0$. Then, for any $t$,
$$
J(t) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial s}(0, t) = (-t \theta'(0) \sin \theta(0), t \theta'(0) \cos \theta(0), 0) = (0, 0, 0).
$$
But then $J \equiv 0$. Therefore no non-trivial Jacobi field along $\gamma$ can vanish at more than one point, which proves that there are no conjugate points to $p$ along $\gamma$.

Comment: @diiiiiklllllll Indeed, do Carmo only proves that meridians are geodesics in that example. But it immediately follows from this and uniqueness of geodesics (with the same starting point and tangent vector) that any geodesic through the origin must be a meridian.

Comment: @diiiiiklllllll For each $s$, the curve $f_s$ is a meridian starting at the origin, so you can find a constant $\theta$ (depending on $s$!) such that, for all $t$, $f_s(t) = (t \cos \theta, t \sin \theta, t^2)$. The angle $\theta$ depends on $s$, so I might as well write it as $\theta(s)$.